# how to add Service-Component header to the bundle manifest file in OSGI declarative services?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, bnd

I am using OSGI declarative services(SCR) to create a component bundle . I am not keen on using the annotation based component xml files generated by maven-scr-plugin . I am writing the component.xml by hand . But, i need the Service-Component header to be added to the MANIFEST file . I am using maven-bundle-plugin to build the osgi bundle , any instructions i can give in the plugin configuration that will add such a header to the manifest file  ?

some useful links :

[felix-SCR](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html)

[maven-scr-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html)

[BND-Service Component](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Components)

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any header which can go in a manifest file can go in the configuration of the bundle plugin as an element. For example,

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>
                  ${pom.artifactId}
                </Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Service-Component>
                 OSGI-INF/some-file.xml
                </Service-Component>
                ....
```

The `<extensions>true</extensions>` line enables arbitrary custom headers, although I believe Service-Component is included in the set of known headers, so it's not needed here.

Comment: i thought maven-bundle-plugin would not understand what service-component element is , works nicely thank you

Comment: The maven-bundle plugin just passes the header along, it does not do anything with. Which is actually not completely true because you can also define components in the header.See http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Components
Curious why you do not want to use the bnd annotations?

Comment: nothing as such , just i did not want to introduce the annotation api depedency in my code .